# How can I conditionally delete rows from a table using data from the same table in a condition?

Tags: mysql

I can not build a query to mysql, to remove the lines from 200 to end.

```
DELETE FROM `popular` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM `popular`
ORDER BY `rank` DESC, `timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 200
)
```

Since an error - #1093 - You can't specify target table 'popular' for update in FROM clause

Comment: As I think, you must translate it to english.

Comment: My apologies, but Stack Overflow is an English language resource, as such this question should be translated into English, either by yourself or by someone else.

Comment: This is one the many MySQL deficiencies in their SQL implementation. You need to change it to use a join instead

Comment: Now that I made your title somewhere close to useful, the _related_ pane shows all the previous questions that cover this in detail. Use a `JOIN`.

Comment: Still cannot build a query. Need help.

Comment: do you have a primary key for your popular table?

Comment: no. I think that it is not useful in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split it into two calls: first run a select and find the ids of the lines you want to delete. then copy these ids and use them on the delete command.

if you don't want to manually add commas between the IDs you can use "find and replace" in textpad or excel can do it really easy.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to rank the rows first then store it on a temporary table and identify the rows to be deleted

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, popular.* from (select @rownum:=0) r, popular order by rank desc, timestamp desc
```